# strange behavior of the iis7 gzip-compress

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, gzip

Good day. I'm trying to configure `gzip-compression` for the site. Put ticks in the settings of the `iis-7` itself.

[image]

Also I wrote the following in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="256">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" /> 
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/css" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/css" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

As a result:

1. For `js` and `css` files, compression works, but for some reason it starts working with 3-4 reload page in the browser after the first launch of the site.
2. After about a minute, do not touch the site, and then restart it, then the files start to load again without compression, it is turned on again after 2-4 reloads the page.
3. Compression does not apply to `bundles`.

Adjustment of the lifetime for compression is not found. The question is what can be done in this situation, so that it works constantly and with `bundles`.

Comment: Only IIS 10 allows you to override compression related settings in `web.config`. Please put such settings in `applicationHost.config` in the global settings (not `location` tag).